# nyromodal : When submitting a form, the name attribute of submit button and its value are not transmitted to server

Tags: jquery, nyromodal

I'm using Nyromodal and I need to have 2 submit buttons ("save", "save and add") in my form and depending on which button I click, my server should redirect me on the right page using the `name` attribute of the `<input type="submit" />`

My problem is when I submit my form, the name attribute of submit's button and its value are not present in the `$_POST` variable.

All works perfectly if I don't display my form with nyroModal.

with nyroModal :

```
array (size=1)
  'form' => 
    array (size=2)
      'title' => string 'azerty' (length=5)
      'date' => string '12/07/2012' (length=10)
```

without nyroModal :

```
array (size=2)
  'form' => 
    array (size=2)
      'title' => string 'azerty' (length=30)
      'date' => string '12/07/2012' (length=10)
  'submit_button_name' => string 'OK' (length=7)
```

anyone have an idea how to do this with nyroModal

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to place an `<input type="hidden" name="" />` in the form and assign a value to the `name` attribute when click on submit button.